# Why isn't PHP Variable carried to the next if statement

Tags: php, variables

I have two if statements, in the first if statement `$date` variable displays fine but in the next if statement, the same `$date` variable is null. How can I carry the same variable with its' assigned value?

```
   if(isset($_POST['find'])){
    $ret= mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM users WHERE city='$cityy' and state='$statee' and schedule_one='0'");
    $num=mysqli_fetch_array($ret);
    $city = $num['city'];
    $state = $num['state'];
    $schedOne = $num['schedule_one_date'];
    $schedOnAddress = $num['schedule_one_address'];
    $date = $schedOne;
    $_POST['schedule_one_date'] = $date;   
   if($num>0){
    //$date is being displayed accordingly
     $date = $num['schedule_one_date'];
     echo "<script>let isBoss = confirm('You got a job available at $city $date');</script>";
    ?>
    <br>

        <p>There is a job offer at <b><?php echo "$city $state"; ?></b></p>
        <p>Scheduled for <b><?php echo "$schedOne"; ?></b></p>
        <form action="" method="post">
            <input id="cancel" type="submit" value="Cancel" name="cancel">
            <div id="content">
        //$date is being displayed accordingly
                <?php echo "$date";?>
            </div>
            <input id="accept" type="submit" value="Accept" name="accept">
        </form>
        <img src="assets/images/searching.gif" width="160px" height="150px">
    <?php
    }
    else
            {
            $extra="index.php";
            echo "<script>window.location.href='".$extra."'</script>";
            }
    ?>
    </center>
    
    <?php
    }
    if(isset($_POST['accept'])){
        $id = $_SESSION['id'];
        //$date variable is NULL
        echo "<script>alert('*No $date');</script>";
    }
```

Is it possible to create a hidden field at the form and assign that value to the hidden field then get it as a `$_POST['$date'] ?

Comment: (by your code provided) If both `if` conditions result true, there is no reason why the second `$date` would be empty.

Comment: Can you try this  ```echo "<script>alert('*No ".$num['schedule_one_date']."');</script>"; ```?

Comment: After  `if(isset($_POST['accept']))`  the first if statement is still true.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this input field to your form where you can pass it on to your `if(isset($_POST['accept']))` conditional statement so you can call it again inside it.

```
<input name="date" type="text" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($schedOne); ?>" hidden>
```

And now you should be able to access that variable like this;

```
if(isset($_POST['accept'])){
    $id = $_SESSION['id'];
    $date = $_POST['date'];
...
```

Answer (score -2):

You can carry but you should separate strings and variables by using dot character in php. You can change your code like this:

```
if(isset($_POST['accept'])){
    $id = $_SESSION['id'];
    //$date variable is NULL
    echo "<script>alert('*No " . $date . "');</script>";
}
```

Comment: How does this solve the problem the OP is having? You do understand the difference between `"` and `'` with respect to `$vars`, right?

Comment: If I display any other variable the way I have written it, that is being displayed fine, that is not the issue, if I was using more than 1 variable what you say makes sense, but how I wrote it is more efficient.

Comment: you start your string with `"` character in php. Using `'` character inside of string is a normal string for php after you started with `"` character. When you wanna finish your string, you should use  `"` character again. Vice versa is same. If you start with `'` character, you can use any number of `"` character inside of that string. This will not break your string. You need to end your string by using `'` character again.

Comment: If you wanna use variable inside of a string with better appearance, you can use your variable like `{$date}` without ending your string.